# How to get size of the volume in one line?

Tags: grep, filesystems, mount, multipath-storage

I have created kubernetes PVC which is creating volume and mounting into a linux host. I need to fetch the size of the volume.

Currently below is the way i am taking volume name and size.

To get the volume name

```
mount | grep pvc-a2811efd-3ea5-4f8d-8e0c-f4b390a3a0c2
```

It displays the mount point as below.

> /dev/mapper/mpathed on
>   /var/lib/kubelet/pods/037656ef-03c1-4b09-be6d-12dd57032218/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-a2811efd-3ea5-4f8d-8e0c-f4b390a3a0c2/mount
>   type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)

Then i am taking the disk size as below.

```
 multipath -ll /dev/mapper/mpathee | grep size
```

It displays the size as below

> size=15G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw

Seems i need to depend on grep. I have to automate this task. Is there any other way i can get the volume size easily in one line? I need to store the volume size 15 in a variable and compare it with the size i given.So if i can get it in one liner it would be great

Comment: have you tried `df -h | grep pvc-a2811efd-3ea5-4f8d-8e0c-f4b390a3a0c2` ? this should provide size.

Comment: @Archemar . I tried it but it is showing nothing . there also i have to get  "df -h /dev/mapper/mpathed"

Comment: I didn't speak fluently docker/kuberletes tools, but along with tool for creation, there should be tools to list size, usage, state, owner, and misceleanous values.